# Insert comma after characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to add comma after some character length but I am failed because my case is different . What I want to achieve I want to insert comma after character length like (1,23,433,4444,55555) upto. If for example character is ( 123 ) . Then I want to insert comma after `1` ( 1,23 ) . If characters is (123433) then I want to insert comma (1,23,433) . Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue .

Thanks

**Code**

```
Convert = (x) => {
    x = x.toString()
    var lastThree = x.substring(x.length - 2)
    var otherNumbers = x.substring(0, x.length - 3)
    if (otherNumbers != '') lastThree = ',' + lastThree
    var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + lastThree
    return res
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what *"after some character length"* means? Do you want to increment the gap between the commas each time, like start with 1 character, then 2 characters, 3 characters and so on?

Comment: Do you want to insert commas with increasing number of digits in between them? Like for an input of `122333444455555666666` do you expect an output of `1,22,333,4444,55555,666666`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try this:

```js
testCase = '123433444455555';

let convert = ([...x]) => {
  let i = 1, subStrings = [];

  while (x.length) {
    subStrings.push(x.splice(0, i).join(""));
    i += 1;
  }

  return subStrings.join(",")
}

let result = convert(testCase);
console.log(result);
```

Making use of [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) we will make an intermediate array of substrings of increasing length. Splice will return the entire string if you attempt to splice more than the current length.

Once the number has been split up appropriately we simply join it with `,` and return the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following,

```js
a = '123433444455555';

const convert = (str) => {
  let step = 1;
  let end = 0;
  while(end + step < str.length -1) {
    str = [str.slice(0, end+step), ',', str.slice(end+step)].join('');
    step++;
    end = end + step;
  }
  return str;
}
let ret = convert(a);
console.log(ret);
```